# Using Java objects for Cucumber testing

Tags: java, cucumber, automated-tests, bdd, cucumber-jvm

How can I pass java objects?

```
Scenario: Java Object test
    When I POST the URL to "/v1/gitlab/project/demo" with <java_object>
    Then I expect to see the response code "200"
    And I expect to see "json" content
```

How can I pass a java object to cucumber in this manner? Or if not java object, then can i pass a json file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can`t pass java objects. You can make a custom transformer through the @Transform annotation but not sure that will help you. I believe for you the best option is to pass JSON string  and then create a JSON object from it in the method. For this you will need the following step definition:

```
@Given("^I have JSON string \"(\\{(^\"]*\\})\"")
public void someMethod(String jsonString) {
}
```

And then in the feature file you can use the following line:

```
Given I have JSON string "{ 'key1' : 'value1', 'key2': 'value2' }"
```

To keep your test clean you may use examples and refer the exact JSON string as variable. Hope this helps.

Comment: Then that JSON String will have an invalid format right? I can't have a single quote. It is considered invalid i think. I will have to escape all the double quotes?

"{ \"key1\" : \"value1\", \"key2\": \"value2\" }".. ?

Comment: Oh yes. You will need to escape them if using directly in the line. If using example tables it may work without escaping

Answer (score 2):

A lot easier to read would be to use a datatable for this:

```
Given I have the following data:
 | property1 | property2 |
 | abc       | 123       |
```

With the following step definition:

```
@Given("^I have the following data:$")
public void given_data(DataTable table) {
    final List<Map<String, String>> rows = table.asMaps(String.class, String.class);
    final Map<String, String> data = rows.get(0);
    final String property1 = data.get("property1");
}
```

I would also suggest only specifying the properties that are relevant for the business case, and add any technical properties inside the step definition. Talking about POST and specific URLs is also already to technical for a cucumber scenario, at least in my opinion.

Comment: I have been following the same approach and saw someone thinking alike. (y)